# Solve double integral using change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration

I am currently learning about Jacobians, and I need help on the following integral:

> $$
> \int_0^3 \int_{y^2}^9 y \cos(x^2) dx dy.
> $$

Comment: hello, welcome to MSE. Please consider using mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to typeset your question. It would also be helpful to know what you tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Please do not write "please help me I need this quickly". If you really want your question to be answered more quickly, see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) so that your question is more presentable.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int_0^3 \int_{y^2}^9 y \cos(x^2) dx dy=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}}\int_{0}^9y \cos(x^2)dxdy=\int_0^9\dfrac{1}{2}x\cos (x^2)dx=\dfrac{\sin 81}{4}. $$

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to represent $\int\cos(x^2)dx$ in terms of elementary functions! This is called the Fresnel integral, see [Fresnel Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral). The best you can do is use series expansions.